# how to remove first two digit number from 4 digit numbers serious of numbers

Tags: php

am using application number generator finction like appilcation number logic:current month.current date count of today.year Ex:09.0801.14 
first one am getting fine if start second insert application using my logic it shows 09.08802.14
i found that $getresult it geeting 0801 so am getting 5 digit application number

```
<?php
  $getresult=explode(".",$getresult);
    if(!isset($getresult))
    {
        $ref_num=$getmonth.$getdate.'01'.$getyear;

    }
    else
    {
        $getresult=intval($getresult[1])+1;
        if($getresult<10)
        {
            $getresult='0'.$getresult;
        }

        else
        {
            $getresult=$getresult; 
        }
        $ref_num=$getmonth.$getdate.$getresult.$getyear;
    }
        ?>
```

here i need to remove  $getresult first two digit number i mean if i get $getresult value 0801 i have change  it to 01.
how can i do this

Comment: i didn't read your code but take a look at substr() preg_match() functions in php.net it will give the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Simple bad but fast fix answer:

```
echo substr('12345', 0, 4)
```

Output will be `1234`

`echo substr('12345', 2, 4);`
Output will be `34`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$getresult = substr($getresult, 2)
```

to remove the first two digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ref_num=substr($ref_num, 2);
```

example:

> 0801 - cuts first 2 letters => 01

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$result = substr($string, 2);
```

api of substr [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)